# I've been using localstorage to try and create a highscore list, but for starters it won't sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, local-storage

Below is the sorting/saving code that I've written, although this code doesn't manage to sort scores properly. And It creates and array for each highscore value, instead of just splicing the names and results alone.

This function sorts and adds all the saved scores into my highscores array. It also removes the lowest score if the array length exceeds 10.

```
function scoreSort() {
  if(that < 10) {
    that ++;
    highscores.splice((highscores.length), 0, 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(that)));
  }

highscores.sort(function(a, b) {return b.score - a.score});
if(highscores.length > 10) highscores.splice(10, 1);
}
```

This one separates all the different saved strings so that I don't get all the scores on the same line.

```
function localStore() {
  localStorage.getItem(number);
  number += JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("numbr"));
  localStorage.setItem("numbr", JSON.stringify(number));
}
```

Here I just make the scores save.

```
function saveScore() {

  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(number), JSON.stringify(highscores));
}



if (playerHP == 0) {
  highscores.splice(1, 0, {name: username, score: score});
  gameState = 'gameover';
  localStore();
  saveScore();
  localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(number), JSON.stringify(highscores));

}
```

I realize this is probably poorly explained and formatted but I'm new to this, so I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: For starters, you don't need to `stringify` or `parse` anything, you can simply store objects directly.

Comment: I tried this earlier but I just got [object, object] instead of the name and score.

Comment: You're right, I could've sworn localStorage handles this appropriately. Regarding the sorting, this works differently in JS: you're not supposed to return the difference but `true`/`false`, i.e. `return a.score < b.score;` My solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/753yyaso/

Comment: This is great, thanks.